# Brightness keys (Fn + Left/Right) on Acer Nitro 5 not working

Tags: drivers, shortcut-keys, brightness, acer, acpi

So, recently (roughly a week ago they were working) the brightness keyboard shortcuts on my Acer have stopped working. I can still change the brightness with the slider in Ubuntu's settings or by changing the value in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`.

Any solution I have found on the interned did not work:

- GRUB ones simply changed nothing
- `xbacklight` does not work, no output in the console
- any solution requiring creating `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` did not work and broke something else (usually GUI, sometimes preventing system booting properly)

I have tried `acpi_listen` and both combinations (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>) produce `676AA15E-6A47- 000000bc 00000000` twice (I think one for press, one for lift, continuous if held). Weirdly, pressing the disable touchpad combination (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, works as intended) gets me the same, but once.

I know next to nothing about hardware, so I'm entirely confused at this point. Would appreciate any help, even if it just explains the weird behavior without solving the issue.

**Configuration:**

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 TLS
- Acer Nitro 5
- i7-7700HQ
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile (driver-390) / Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630

Comment: same here nitro an515-58. brightness-control package from apt is the only thing that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it finally. Issue was related to NVIDIA drivers. I was using older driver (390), because it was the only one that allowed me to play sound over HDMI. Not sure what broke it, but switching to the newest driver (460) in Software & Updates made the brightness keys work properly.

Sound over HDMI does not work properly with the newest driver, unfortunately.

`acpi_listen` still shows `676AA15E-6A47- 000000bc 00000000` as descripted above, but additionally there is `video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000` or `video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000`
. Order of codes varies.

Answer (score 0):

In Grub add/change to, the magic line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_acklight=native"

This works on mine for the Brightness control Saw it referred to in the Acer Community blog. It actually comes from a youtube video.

The keyboard light has a setting in the uefi. Timeout or not.